# Programmatically creating a continuous scrolling background in Game Maker: Studio

Tags: game-maker, side-scroller, scrolling, shooter

I have 15 background images for a 2D horizontal scrolling shooter game and I have been wondering how to insert programmatically those background images in the first level room, as I want them to be displayed one after the other looking as they were one large background image, repeating the last four ones until the boss is defeated.

[image]

I have seen that in Game Maker: Studio only 8 background slots are available in each room, so how could I achieve doing what I need here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To dynamically scroll through a very large background made up of smaller frames, there are many different solution; the main idea though is quite the same.

**The main idea**
Think of your fifteen background frames as sort of "panels", which you draw one along the other so that they fit the current `view` width: if your view is 1280 pixels wide, and each background is 960 pixels wide, then you need at least three backgrounds per time to fit the current `view`; this looks obvious if one of the "panels" fits within the current view:

[image]

**Cycling through panels**
With this setup, we expect background **1** in the image to disappear as soon as it lies completely out of our `view` borders; later, when background **3** find itself completely within the `view` borders, we need to draw the new background **4** following the number **3** seamlessly.

**Make it simpler**
We can tear down the global complexity of our solution by making some considerations:

- We can use a fixed number of scrolling panels (backgrounds) as long as they fit the `view` range, as showed ealier, in number equal to or greater that the minimum required;
- In GM:S, since we have a limited number of available backgrounds, instead of loosing past backgrounds and allocating new ones (not possible because background indices are fixed in GM:S), we can just shift the `background_index`es in a proper way to make the whole bigger background be drawn seamlessly.

All this realizes as follow. First, we draw the first *n* backgrounds; when the *n*-th background lies within the `view` borders, thus we now need to draw the *n+1*-th background, we shift the *n* backgrounds back (for example, along the positive direction of *x* axis) of value *n*background_width*; finally, we make the *n*-th background equal to the first - so that it will actually be drawn in the same previous position regarding the room `view` - and then assign the new backgrounds to the indices to follow.

If we make *n = 5*, we reach the following:

- Starting cycle: backgrounds **1** to **5**;
- First iteration: backgrounds **5** to **9**;
- Second iteration: backgrounds **9** to **13**;
- Boss iterations: backgrounds **13**, **14**, **15**, **12**, **13**

The "boss iteration" will occur through the same backgrounds continuously and seamlessly, thanks to a useful choice of numbers.

**Implementation**
Have one object to control directly the background movement.

In its *Create Event*, you assign the backgrounds and their offsets:

```
// Assign background indices
background_index[0] = bgFrame0;
background_index[1] = bgFrame1;
background_index[2] = bgFrame2;
background_index[3] = bgFrame3;
background_index[4] = bgFrame4;

// Shift backgrounds (otherwise they will be overlapped)
for (var i=1; i<5; i++)               // bkgr0 starts at (0,0)
    background_x[i] += i*bk_width;    // bk_width is the width of single backgrounds
```

Then, in the *Step Event* (or similar):

```
// Update backgrounds' relative positions
for (var i=0; i<5; i++)
    background_x[i] -= 5;                 // an alternative to background_hspeed[]

// Change the backgrounds stack when needed
if (background_x[4]<=0)                   // if the last background lies within the view
{
    for (var i=0; i<5; i++)               // push back all five backgrounds
        background_x[i] += bk_width;      // (maintaining their relative offsets)
    background_index[0] = background_index[4]; // last panel becomes the first one

    // change other backgrounds here
}
```

**Final touch**
Where I commented `// change other backgrounds here`, you can implement a `switch` statement that changes `background_index[1]` to `background_index[4]` upon looking up a counter variable telling you which background cycle to draw (starting, first, second, or boss).

Important thing is, before changing these `background_index`es, you must always execute `background_index[0] = background_index[4]` to make the transition seamless.

Comment: Thank you very much for this. Sadly though it doesn't work for me. It works fine until background[4]'s x reaches 0 (here probably "if (background_x[4]<=0)")
and the it changes background[4] abruptly to background[3] and those 2 cycle that way perpetually. I'm trying to find a fix

Answer (score 1):

I figured out a workaround. As i posted before, I don't know for sure if the code above works but if it doesn't you can try this one out.It is based on the one above but I also put variables in case you want to change the number of backgrounds. My workaround needs the duplication of the last bg.

```
Create Event:


bgNum = 6  //The total number of bgs plus 1(the duplicate)

background_index[0] = bg0 //the bg you want to appear LAST
background_index[1] = bg1 //The ACTUAL bg you want to see FIRST
background_index[2] = bg2
background_index[3] = bg3
background_index[4] = bg4

background_index[bgNum-1] = background_index[0] //the duplicate last bg

bk_width = 3840 //my width is double my view's width but you can try your         own

var i;           //fill array

i = bgNum-1;
repeat(bgNum)
   {
   background_x[i] = 0
   i -= 1;
   }

// Shift backgrounds (otherwise they will be overlapped)

for (var i=1; i<bgNum; i++)   // bkgr0 starts at (0,0)
{
background_x[i] += i*bk_width;
}

for (var i=0; i<bgNum; i++) 
{
background_x[i] -= bk_width; //move to the one you want first
}

Step Event:

// Update backgrounds' relative positions

for (var i=0; i<bgNum; i++)
background_x[i] -= key;    // an alternative to background_hspeed[]

//when the last bg reaches 0
if (background_x[bgNum-1]<=-0)  // if the last background lies within the     view

{
for (var i=0; i<bgNum; i++)  //push back all backgrounds so that bg0 replaces
{                                //the last bg which has the same sprite
background_x[i] += bk_width*(bgNum-1); //so the transition is seamless
}
}
```

Big thanx to liggiorgio who posted the original code it was really helpful and sorry for the poor formating